# Do I use the Siemens Type Q Breaker in ITE Blueline Loadcenter panel?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, subpanel

I'm looking for compatible breakers for my old ITE Blueline Loadcenter main panel.  I believe ITE was bought by Siemens.  Would the Siemens 100A 2 Pole 120/240V Type Q Breaker (https://www.homedepot.ca/product/siemens-100a-2-pole-120-240v-type-q-breaker/1000436969) be compatible for supplying 100A sub-panel?

Update:
I noticed one newer Siemens breaker in the panel! It's labelled type BL.  Can I assume all type BL breakers will be compatible with my ITE Blueline Loadcenter panel?

Update:
Photos added.

Photos:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the labeling on the inside of your panel's door please?

Comment: well unfortunately there is no labeling on the inside of the panel's door... or anywhere else on the panel

Comment: ah but I did just notice one newer Siemens breaker in the panel! Its type BL.

Comment: Can you post whatever photos of the panel you have please then?

Comment: I posted photos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are looking for a Siemens BL2 (not to be confused with a Siemens BL)

ITE Blue Line loadcenters appear to use a special style of "thin" breaker instead of the more "typical" QP (EQ-P) breaker.  Unfortunately, the ITE Blue Line (not to be confused with the *other* type BL breaker, which is the bolt-down version of the QP and thus no use to you), only is available in 1 pole up to 50A and 2 pole up to 40A, as per [the current Siemens Canada catalog](https://assets.new.siemens.com/siemens/assets/api/uuid:12541abc-9f2a-438c-8d1e-ea91e30716fd/power-product-catalogue-complete-jul-2020.pdf).  So, you'll either need to run a smaller feeder to your subpanel, or have your main panel replaced outright.

Comment: ouff... I was hoping to future proof for possible solar (I think I need at least 60A 2 pole for that) but I guess that's a future problem.  The 40A is more than enough more my current needs.  Pun not intended.

Comment: follow up:  the BL2-040 is the 2 pole 40A breaker.  So I need the 8/3 wire for that?

Comment: @jpx -- yea, that'd go with 8/3...